# Low Search - have channel as search criteria

Tags: low-search, ee

I've been wrestling with this for too long and it's doing my head in now!

I am using the low search plugin for expressionengine and want to search:
a) by keyword (which is working fine)
b) by channel - selected by dropdown (which I can't get to work)

So the results would show channel entries with the relevant keywords ONLY in the selected channel.

Currently I have:

```
{exp:low_search:form 
        form_class="header-search"
        form_id="search-keywords"
        required="keywords"
        result_page="search/results"
}
            <select name="searchChannel">
                <option value="channel1|channel2">All</option>
                <option value="channel1">Channel1</option>
                <option value="channel2">Channel2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="keywords"id="keywords">
            <input type="submit">
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

results page:

```
{exp:low_search:results 
   disable="{gv:disable_default}" 
   limit="18"
   orderby_sort="title|asc"
   query="{segment_3}"  
}
```

I can pass through the searchChannel field through to the results page by adding:

```
{low_search_searchChannel}
```

to the results page; and of course I can set the channel filter in the results page by hard coding it:

```
channel="channel1"
```

but if I try:

```
channel="{low_search_searchChannel}"
```

I get nothing. There's probably a better way anyway to pass it straight in via the form tag, but have tried everything I can think of!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to approach it like that. Low Search handles both native and custom parameters the same: [like this](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params). So **any parameter can be an input field**.

That means that if you name your select element `channel`, you're already done, eg:

```
<select name="channel">
  <option value="channel1|channel2">All</option>
  <option value="channel1">Channel1</option>
  <option value="channel2">Channel2</option>
</select>
```

No need to set the `channel=""` param on the Results tag, let alone for PHP in your template.

Better still, since you're using the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords), you might want to consider targeting the `collection` param rather than `channel`, eg:

```
<select name="collection">
  <option value="">All</option>
  {collections}
    <option value="{collection_name}">{collection_label}</option>
  {/collections}
</select>
```

Comment: YAY!!! changed the select name and works a treat! helps if you've written the plugin I guess! ;op My fault for misinterpreting the documentation - useful to know for the future. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score -1):

Ahhh, good old parse order :)

`{low_search_searchChannel}` can't be parsed until it is inside of the `{exp:low_search:results }` I would suspect. How about a little PHP to get you out of stuck-ville?

*PHP on Input*

```
<?php 
    $query = ee()->uri->segment(3);
    $query = json_decode(base64_decode($query));
    //validate your channel here
    $channel = 'channel1|channel2'; //default
    if ( !empty ( $query->searchChannel ) ) { 
        $channel = $query->searchChannel;
    }
?>
{exp:low_search:results 
    disable="{gv:disable_default}" 
    limit="18"
    orderby_sort="title|asc"
    query="{segment_3}"  
    channel="<?php echo $channel ; ?>"
}
```

This should check if searchChannel was submitted (you can further check it where I put the comment) and fetch it into a PHP variable, completely seperate from low_search. on output if `$channel` is empty (perhaps someone tried to inject something and it got cleaned) it puts the default channels in, synonymous with your All option.

Give that a little try and see how you get on.

**Edit**

Added code to examplify how to decode the Low Search URL parameter...

PS> Making a site about biking or holidays per chance?? lol, I decoded your example from the comments, channel = tours, keywords = france.... :D

Comment: I like your thinking, I know where I am better with PHP - none of this new fangled EE malarky! Unfortunately, if I echo out the ee()->input->post('searchChannel'), it comes out blank. I have checked PHP is enabled for the template and the PHP parsing is set to INPUT.

Comment: I'm wondering if low-search doesn't POST inputs, but passes them through encrypted in the URL as there is a big crazy string in the URL: results/eyJyZXN1bHRfcGFnZSI6InNlYXJjaFwvcmVzdWx0cyIsInNlYXJjaENoYW5uZWwiOiJ0b3VycyIsImtleXdvcmRzIjoiZnJhbmNlIiwieCI6IjAiLCJ5IjoiMCJ9

Comment: Good point, this seems to be a redirect from an action. can you inspect the search form and tell us the action attribute please? This will tell us if it's posting to an action URL and forwarding you to big crazy string result page, or not. FYI, the big crazy string is a Base64 encoded JSON array, the one you posted is : `{"result_page":"search\/results","searchChannel":"touróm8óm7s","keywords":"france","x":"0","y":"0"}`, I'll factor this into my answer!

Comment: Forget my last question, worked it out. Please see my edited answer above! That should get you there!!

Comment: hehe! check out your hacking! yes, tour related site! Still no juicy I'm afraid... I think you hit the nail on the head with the 'parse order' diagnosis. Your edit does capture the input, but the trouble ee is having I think now is that if PHP is parsed on input, I believe all the PHP variables are parsed into strings before the EE code gets to run (I'm just guessing there), but if the PHP is parsed on output, the EE code will run without the parsed PHP (again, not TOTALLY sure on that).

Comment: I'd have thought adding `channel="{low_search_searchChannel}"` to the restults tag should work, but the trouble seems to be actually passing ANYTHING into those tags - PHP, EE whatever!

Comment: I do **not** recommend this solution. Please see my answer for the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks Low, I agree with your answer as preferred (RTFM fails all over the place), though technically my approch is a valid answer too. It's what low_search does when parsing tags anyway. @nick, Just on the PHP parsing (use [Low's parse order cheetsheet](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf), they've been doing this a while!) I've used PHP on input to dynamically set module tags before, the point is PHP is parsed before module tags ergo once low_search parses the results tag the PHP should have been executed already.

Comment: thanks @Blantant for your help... cheers too for the tip on Low's cheetsheet., will check that out. Beer's on me next time :)

Comment: No problem Nick, your thanks/beer tokens should be directed to Low though. Always better to get it 'from the horse's mouth' so to speak (Not that you're a horse or anything Low!!) Learn that parse order, it will help you so much inthe future, especially if you're like me and hack and slash PHP code willy nilly!

Comment: I guess that *technically* it's an answer, but using PHP in your template is generally considered bad practice, and in this case is totally unnecessary to achieve the desired result to boot. It's like driving from London to Brighton via Dublin.